# Join tables and bring data even if they don't match?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

This is my data stored in 2 tables.

Table `calendar`:

| Company | CalendarDate | CalendarID | WorkingHours |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CompOne | 2023-09-08 | Sup-01 | 8 |
| CompOne | 2023-09-08 | Sup-02 | 8 |
| CompOne | 2023-09-08 | Sup-03 | 8 |
| CompOne | 2023-09-08 | Sup-04 | 8 |
| CompTwo | 2023-09-08 | Sup-01 | 8 |
| CompTwo | 2023-09-08 | Sup-02 | 8 |
| CompTwo | 2023-09-08 | Sup-03 | 8 |
| CompTwo | 2023-09-08 | Sup-04 | 8 |

Table `timesheet`:

| Company | CalendarDate | CalendarID | TimesheetHour | Employee |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CompOne | 2023-09-08 | Sup-01 | 8 | Matt Jr. |
| CompOne | 2023-09-08 | Sup-02 | 8 | Jonas Ls |
| CompOne | 2023-09-08 | Sup-03 | 8 | Julie Wr |
| CompOne | 2023-09-08 | Sup-04 | 8 | Amanda P |
| CompTwo | 2023-09-08 | Sup-01 | 8 | Joseph R |
| CompTwo | 2023-09-08 | Sup-02 | 8 | Tom Greg |
| CompTwo | 2023-09-08 | Sup-03 | 8 | Paul Kin |
| CompTwo | 2023-09-08 | Sup-04 | 8 | David Op |

The `timesheet` table doesn't save the days that you didn't have clocked in, so if you worked 4 days in a week (Monday-Thursday), Friday won't appear.

What I want to do is to bring the 'timesheethour' even if I bring it like 0

So, basically I'm trying to get something like this:

| Company | CalendarDate | CalendarID | WorkingHours | Employee | TimesheetHour |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CompOne | 2023-09-07 | Sup-01 | 8 | Matt Jr. | 8 |
| CompOne | 2023-09-07 | Sup-02 | 8 | Jonas Ls | 8 |
| CompOne | 2023-09-08 | Sup-01 | 8 | Matt Jr. | 8 |
| CompOne | 2023-09-08 | Sup-02 | 8 | Jonas Ls | 0 |
| CompOne | 2023-09-09 | Sup-01 | 8 | Matt Jr. | 0 |
| CompOne | 2023-09-09 | Sup-02 | 8 | Jonas Ls | 0 |
| CompOne | 2023-09-10 | Sup-01 | 8 | Matt Jr. | 0 |
| CompOne | 2023-09-10 | Sup-02 | 8 | Jonas Ls | 8 |
| CompOne | 2023-09-11 | Sup-01 | 8 | Matt Jr. | 8 |
| CompOne | 2023-09-11 | Sup-02 | 8 | Jonas Ls | 8 |
| CompOne | 2023-09-12 | Sup-01 | 8 | Matt Jr. | 8 |
| CompOne | 2023-09-12 | Sup-02 | 8 | Jonas Ls | 0 |
| CompOne | 2023-09-13 | Sup-01 | 8 | Matt Jr. | 0 |
| CompOne | 2023-09-13 | Sup-02 | 8 | Jonas Ls | 8 |
| CompOne | 2023-09-14 | Sup-01 | 8 | Matt Jr. | 0 |
| CompOne | 2023-09-14 | Sup-02 | 8 | Jonas Ls | 0 |
| CompOne | 2023-09-15 | Sup-01 | 8 | Matt Jr. | 0 |
| CompOne | 2023-09-15 | Sup-02 | 8 | Jonas Ls | 8 |

Could it be 0 or null, but just bringing the data is ok for me.

I tried with this query:

```
WITH calendar AS 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT
        CalendarID,
        CalendarDate,
        Company,
        SUM((ENDTIME - STARTTIME) * EFFICIENCYPERCENTAGE / 100 / 3600) AS WorkingHours
    FROM 
        Calendar
    GROUP BY 
        CalendarDate, CalendarID, Company 
),
timesheet AS 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT
        Employee,
        CalendarDate,
        Company,
        CalendarID,
        TTimesheetHour
    FROM 
        Timesheet
)
SELECT
    cal.Company,
    cal.CalendarDate,
    cal.CalendarID,
    cal.WorkingHours,
    ts.Employee,
    COALESCE(ts.WorkingHours, 0) 'TimesheetHour'
FROM 
    calendar cal
FULL OUTER JOIN 
    timesheet ts ON ts.CalendarID = cal.CalendarID,
                 AND ts.CalendarDate = cal.CalendarDate
                 AND ts.Company = cal.Company
WHERE 
    cal.CalendarDate BETWEEN '2023-09-07' AND '2023-09-10'
    AND ((ts.Employee LIKE 'Matt Jr%') OR 
         ((ts.Employee LIKE 'Jonas Ls%'))
```

but still without results that I want, and I've tried with cross join but at least the way I'm trying is not working

Answer (score 0):

Your `where` clause filters out the rows that the `full outer join` lets through:

```
FULL OUTER JOIN
        timesheet ts
ON      ts.CalendarDate = ts.CalendarDate
WHERE   ts.Employee LIKE 'Matt Jr%'
```

These rows are filtered out because `NULL LIKE 'Matt Jr%'` evaluates to `null`, which is not true.

You could explitly allow these rows by adding:

```
FULL OUTER JOIN
        timesheet ts
ON      ts.CalendarDate = ts.CalendarDate
WHERE   ts.Employee LIKE 'Matt Jr%'
        OR ts.Employee IS NULL
```

Or you could move the `ts.Employee LIKE` checks to the `on` clause of your `full outer join`:

```
FULL OUTER JOIN
        timesheet ts
ON      ts.CalendarDate = ts.CalendarDate
        AND ts.Employee LIKE 'Matt Jr%'
WHERE   ...
```

Comment: It didn't worked. I've tried both ways and none is right.

Answer (score 0):

You need to go with the following logic:

```
[Required employees] CROSS JOIN [Calendar - all days] LEFT JOIN [Timesheet]
```

Considering that you have an employees table:

```
WITH calendar AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT
        CalendarID,
        CalendarDate,
        Company,
        SUM((ENDTIME - STARTTIME) * EFFICIENCYPERCENTAGE / 100 / 3600) AS WorkingHours
    FROM Calendar
    GROUP BY CalendarDate, CalendarID, Company
),
timesheet AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT
        Employee,
        CalendarDate,
        Company,
        CalendarID,
        TTimesheetHour AS WorkingHours  -- Alias the column for consistency
    FROM Timesheet
)

SELECT
    cal.Company,
    cal.CalendarDate,
    cal.CalendarID,
    COALESCE(cal.WorkingHours, 0) AS WorkingHours,
    ts.Employee,
    COALESCE(ts.WorkingHours, 0) AS TimesheetHour
FROM
    employees e -- ADDED THIS TABLE AND CROSS JOINED
    cross join calendar cal
FULL OUTER JOIN
    timesheet ts ON
        ts.CalendarID = cal.CalendarID
        AND ts.CalendarDate = cal.CalendarDate
        AND ts.Company = cal.Company
        AND ts.employee = e.employee -- ADDED THIS CONDITION
WHERE
    cal.CalendarDate BETWEEN '2023-09-07' AND '2023-09-10'
    --  WHERE CONDITION ON EMPLOYEE TABLE (e.)
    AND (e.Employee LIKE 'Matt Jr%' OR e.Employee LIKE 'Jonas Ls%');
```

**Note:** If you dont have `EMPLOYEES` table, You can use one more `CTE` as `EMPLOYEE` with `SELECT DISTINCT employee from Timesheet` table.

Comment: Hello! I've tried this, but it didn't worked as well. It gets me results with CalendarID's that doesn't correspond to Matt, and didn't even brought Jonas.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like there are a couple of issues in your SQL query. I've made some modifications to address these issues, primarily by fixing syntax errors and adjusting the conditions in the **ON** clause of the **FULL OUTER JOIN**. Here's the corrected query:

```sql
WITH calendar AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT
        CalendarID,
        CalendarDate,
        Company,
        SUM((ENDTIME - STARTTIME) * EFFICIENCYPERCENTAGE / 100 / 3600) AS WorkingHours
    FROM Calendar
    GROUP BY CalendarDate, CalendarID, Company
),
timesheet AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT
        Employee,
        CalendarDate,
        Company,
        CalendarID,
        TTimesheetHour AS WorkingHours  -- Alias the column for consistency
    FROM Timesheet
)

SELECT
    cal.Company,
    cal.CalendarDate,
    cal.CalendarID,
    COALESCE(cal.WorkingHours, 0) AS WorkingHours,
    ts.Employee,
    COALESCE(ts.WorkingHours, 0) AS TimesheetHour
FROM
    calendar cal
FULL OUTER JOIN
    timesheet ts ON
        ts.CalendarID = cal.CalendarID
        AND ts.CalendarDate = cal.CalendarDate
        AND ts.Company = cal.Company
WHERE
    cal.CalendarDate BETWEEN '2023-09-07' AND '2023-09-10'
    AND (ts.Employee LIKE 'Matt Jr%' OR ts.Employee LIKE 'Jonas Ls%');
```

This query should provide you with a result set that includes rows for each combination of **CalendarDate**, **CalendarID**, and Employee, with the corresponding **WorkingHours** from the Calendar table and **TimesheetHour** from the **Timesheet** table. If a combination is missing in either table, the result will still include that row with 0 values. Adjust the date range and employee conditions as needed.

The query results for the date range '2023-09-07' to '2023-09-10' with employees 'Matt Jr.' and 'Jonas Ls':

```yaml
| Company | CalendarDate | CalendarID | WorkingHours | Employee  | TimesheetHour |
|---------|--------------|------------|--------------|-----------|---------------|
| CompOne | 2023-09-07   | Sup-01     | 8            | Matt Jr.  | 8             |
| CompOne | 2023-09-07   | Sup-02     | 8            | Jonas Ls  | 8             |
| CompOne | 2023-09-08   | Sup-01     | 8            | Matt Jr.  | 8             |
| CompOne | 2023-09-08   | Sup-02     | 8            | Jonas Ls  | 0             |
| CompOne | 2023-09-09   | Sup-01     | 8            | Matt Jr.  | 0             |
| CompOne | 2023-09-09   | Sup-02     | 8            | Jonas Ls  | 0             |
| CompOne | 2023-09-10   | Sup-01     | 8            | Matt Jr.  | 0             |
| CompOne | 2023-09-10   | Sup-02     | 8            | Jonas Ls  | 8             |
```

This is just an example, and the actual results may vary based on the data in your database.

Comment: It didn't worked. Only got me a single line with the actual appointment.